# Lightweight python wiki engine with pluggable auth system

Tags: python, wiki-engine

I need to add wiki to my Tornado webapp. i'm new to python so i would like it not too intimidating to be learned and integrated and can use my existing authentication system, hence the lightweight. it would be better if can use mongodb backend.

I already take a look at moin-moin and it seems too complex(?). any other alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Hatta](http://hatta-wiki.org/). Overwrite `WikiRequest.get_author()` method to plug your authentication system. But it uses mercurial repository to store the data.

Comment: looks simple enough. need to see if i can use tornado templating instead of WikiPage.

Answer (score 0):

[Skeletonz](http://orangoo.com/skeletonz/) is a very nice lightweight Python cms that might be worth a look...